# there are no errors in the models, but when I create a migration, this is displayed

Tags: python, django

(venv) PS C:\django-sites\testsite> python manage.py makemigrations

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'admin' isn't unique.
You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
No changes detected

(venv) PS C:\django-sites\testsite>

deleted every line in path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

my code:

```
from django.db import models


class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)




#id - INT
#title - Varchar
#content - Text
#createrd_at - DateTime
#updated_at - DateTime
#photo - Image
#is_published - Boolean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the migrations folder, to create initial migrations for an app, run makemigrations and specify the app name. The migrations folder will be created.

In your case it would be:

```
python manage.py makemigrations news
```

And of course, your app must be included in INSTALLED_APPS inside settings.py ( news.apps.NewsConfig )